# pulling data from database wth ajax and when i click on a href it dose not work

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am really having hard time with small problem - I am still learning jQuery
let me explain what is the problem

I am pulling data from database using jQuery - 
after that data pulled out from Database will appended it to the div dataHolder, every thing is fine until now.

however the  `***<a id="set" style="cursor: pointer;">Confirm Date</a>***` when I click on it - the click event dose not fire up.... I just don't why, I have test this link in different page and seems to be working but here it dose not fire up - any help - thanks in advanced

let me show you the script

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#set").click(function(){

                  // do something
              alert( 'ok' );

        });

        $('#myform').on('change',function( e ){

            e.preventDefault();

            var select = $('#select').val();
            // ** console.log(select);

            var datasholder = $('#dataHolder').html('');

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'proccess.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data ){
                    datasholder.append( data );
                }

            })  
        })  
    })


    </script>

  <form action="proccess.php" id="myform" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">

   <label for="find">Qualified / Unqalifed Report</label>
   <select name="find" id="select">

        <option vlaue="">Select option...!</option>
        <option value="2">qualifed</option>
        <option value="3">unqualifed</option>

   </select>

   </form>

   <div id="dataHolder">
   // ** WHEN DATA PULLED FROM DB WILL BE HERE - for example    

   <tr>
       <th>Name:</th>
       <th>email:</th>
       <th>Confirm Date</th>
   </tr>

   <tr>
       <td>Name:</td>
       <td>email:</td>
       <td><a id="set" style="cursor: pointer;">Confirm Date</a></td>
   </tr>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use delegation with [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$("#dataHolder").on('click','#set',function(){

                  // do something
              alert( 'ok' );

        });
```